# Enable group-policy using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, group-policy, gpo

If one wanted to permanently enable or disable a GPO, how would one go about doing so using a batch file?
I'm trying to create a batch file that changes the settings that says "Always use custom logon background" so that it the custom background of my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying group policies programmatically is hairy and dangerous.  (See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377617/#14690214) for adding a startup script to group policy.)  I'm not sure specifically where the setting is for "Always use custom logon background" in the registry, but I'm certain that there's more than one value you'll have to modify for the result you're expecting.

You're really better off using Windows' [Group Policy Management Editor](http://mikecrowley.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-set-windows-7s-login-wallpaper-with-group-policies/).

Answer (score 0):

Allowing access to the Group Policy is possible via a batch script. What you may need though to access it are permissions to utilize the registry. (not verified)

The commands needed go as follows:

```
reg delete "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft" /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft" /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy  Objects" /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies" /f
```

This should remove any Group Policy settings preventing you from accessing the registry. I am making a script like this on my own so I thought that this could come in handy here.

Also please note that this is for enabling the Group Policy editor only, not disabling it. You can also manually set the group policy access setting in the group policy editor.